# File locking from different therads of the same process, including for Solaris OS

Tags: linux, solaris, c, multithreading, ipc

I need to perform a file lock when accessing a file from C/C++ code with the following requirements:

1. Blocking should be performed when access occurs not only from different processes, but also from different threads of the same process
2. It should work for Linux and Solaris OS

I found [fcntl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) (Open file description locks (non-POSIX)) and [flock](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html), which satisfy the first requirement. But unfortunately these APIs are missing in Solaris

What is the best way to complete my task? I would like to use only one feature to prevent simultaneous writing to a file. Without using mutexes to synchronize threads and fcntl (for example) to synchronize processes.

Comment: `fcntl` does appear to be in Solaris, [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29032/fcntl-2.html]. Also, try looking ar [https://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/solaris-portability-flock.html]

Comment: @Bib `fcntl` present in Solaris, but the version of `fcntl` which Solaris has does not satisfied my 1st requirement. In linux, to meet the first requirement, you need to use`fcntl` with `F_OFD_SETLK`/`F_OFD_SETLKW` macros which do not seem to exist in Solaris

Comment: @Bib Both of the links you provided lead to "page not found"

Comment: Remove the `]` at the end. I was responding to your assertion that they do do not exist, `fcntl` does.

Comment: @ibse Solaris implements portable locking per [POSIX `fcntl()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/fcntl.html) and [POSIX `lockf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/fcntl.html), neither of which support thread-level locking.  The `F_OFD_SETLK/F_OFD_SETLKW` macros are clearly described in the Linux man page as non-POSIX and therefore non-portable.  Expecting them to exist in Solaris is almost akin to expecting Windows file locking functionality to exist in Linux.

Comment: And this really looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What is the **problem** that you have that you've already decided that file locking is the solution for?